# Make a Label take all available space across an HBox in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, layout

In JavaFX 21, I want an `HBox` to contain 3 elements, a label and two buttons.

```
HBox rowBox = new HBox ( label , buttonX , buttonY );
```

By default, the widgets all pile up to the left.

Like this with little text, if we imagine my outer square brackets to be the `HBox` boundaries, and inner square brackets to be the boundaries of each button:

> `[ Short text. [ buttonX ] [ buttonY] ]`

… or this with more text:

> `[ Or lots and lots and lots of text. [ buttonX ] [ buttonY] ]`

But I want the two buttons to always be on the far right side, like this:

> `[ Short text.                             [ buttonX ] [ buttonY] ]`

> `[ Or lots and lots and lots of text.      [ buttonX ] [ buttonY] ]`

I tried [`HBox.setHgrow`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/21/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/layout/HBox.html#setHgrow(javafx.scene.Node,javafx.scene.layout.Priority)):

```
HBox.setHgrow ( label , Priority.ALWAYS );
```

… but the effect of that does not net me any benefit — the elements remain in the same position. In contrast, I want all the unallocated space of the box to go to the width of the label. I want the label to "push" the two buttons over to the right side of the box.

I am trying to accomplish this layout with a single `HBox` so that I can neatly align the widgets along the baseline of their text.

```
rowBox.setAlignment ( Pos.BASELINE_LEFT );
```

Is there some way to allocate all extra space to the label?

If not, is there some other way to get this buttons-to-the-right layout?

Comment: By the way, I asked this as a part of a possible solution to this Question, [*Left Justify Buttons Inside of an HBox (inside a pagnition if that matters)*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77298240/642706).

Comment: Note the reason `HBox.setHgrow(label, ALWAYS)` doesn't work is because `Label`, by default, has its `maxWidth` set to `USE_COMPUTED_SIZE` and `LabeledSkinBase` simply returns the preferred size from `computeMaxWidth`. If you want to let a `Label` grow in width infinitely, you need to manually set its max width property to positive infinity or the maximum double value.

Comment: Related: [How to align a button right in JavaFX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39214586/how-to-align-a-button-right-in-javafx/39215780#39215780) and [similar for a Toolbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30832692/how-to-create-toolbar-with-left-center-and-right-sections-in-javafx/30834057#30834057).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In JavaFX, to achieve the layout you're describing—where the two buttons are always on the far right and the label takes up all the remaining space—you can use a combination of `HBox`, `Region`, and `HBox.setHgrow`.

Here's how:

1. Create a `Region` that will act as a spacer between your label and buttons.
2. Use `HBox.setHgrow` to make the `Region` take up all the available space.

Here's a code example:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.Priority;
import javafx.scene.layout.Region;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Label label = new Label("Or lots and lots and lots of text.");
        
        Button buttonX = new Button("buttonX");
        Button buttonY = new Button("buttonY");
        
        // Create a region to act as a horizontal spacer
        Region spacer = new Region();
        
        // Make the spacer Region expand as much as possible
        HBox.setHgrow(spacer, Priority.ALWAYS);
        
        HBox hbox = new HBox(label, spacer, buttonX, buttonY);
        
        Scene scene = new Scene(hbox, 400, 100);
        
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

In this example, the `Region` named `spacer` will take up all the extra horizontal space in the `HBox`, pushing your buttons to the far right. The label will take up only as much space as it needs for its text, while `spacer` fills up the remaining space. This ensures your buttons remain on the far right regardless of the label's width.

Comment: Related question: Going the other direction, when user resizes window to be less wide, is there a way to make the `Label` truncate its text so the buttons remain visible rather than disappearing off the right edge of the window?

Comment: @BasilBourque That should be the default behavior. The label's and buttons' parent layout will shrink them as much as they allow in order to fit within the available space. And all `Labeled` will automatically truncate, at least by default. How is controlled by the [`textOverrun`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/21/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/Labeled.html#textOverrunProperty) property. If you're seeing the buttons go off screen, then likely the `HBox` is also larger than you think.

Comment: @Slaw The behavior I describe in that comment came from what I saw in [this Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77299545/642706) of mine that used the `HBox` here as the rows within a `ListView` alone in the center of a `BorderPane`.

Comment: @BasilBourque Yes, `ListView` can be a little strange. But that's because it's a view port. As far as I can tell, it lets its cells shrink horizontally until the cell reaches its preferred width (based on its contents). From there, if the cell gets any smaller, it simply clips the cell and shows the horizontal scroll bar. A label's/button's preferred width is enough space to display all its text. That's why you don't see the any truncating in this case. If I recall correctly, this can cause issues with situations like wanting to wrap text at the current width of the list view.

Comment: @BasilBourque I don't remember if there's a way to alter this behavior easily. At best, there's a property that can be set. Though it might require subclassing the skin of list view and/or list cell; or, at worst, completely rewriting the skins.